# Create a virtual host on apache2

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I have a issue with creating a virtual host on apache2. My website is hosted on a debian 10 sever. I added the file `domain.conf` at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Inside the `domain.conf` file I simply wrote:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that whenever I tip any serveralias like `xyz.domain.com` or `test.domain.com` it opens the `index.php` from `/var/www/domain`. But I only want to allow `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a domain doesn't match a virtual host, one of two locations will be used.

First possibility is the base config, i.e. what you specify in the default config outside any virtual host.  So check the `DocumentRoot` in the base config (try `grep DocumentRoot /etc/apache2/*` if you don't know where to look).

Second, if you want an "all vhost" config, you can mask the base config by creating a vhost with the same `ServerName` and IP/port config as the base config.
Create a dummy virtual host in a config like `aaa.conf` with the same `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` as the base config which either sends the user to a sandbox, or returns an error, or redirects to `www.example.com`, or whatever action you choose.

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html

> Main host goes away
>
> Any request that doesn't match an existing
>  is handled by the global server configuration,
> regardless of the hostname or ServerName.
>
> When you add a name-based virtual host to an existing server, and the
> virtual host arguments match preexisting IP and port combinations,
> requests will now be handled by an explicit virtual host. In this
> case, it's usually wise to create a default virtual host with a
> ServerName matching that of the base server. New domains on the same
> interface and port, but requiring separate configurations, can then be
> added as subsequent (non-default) virtual hosts.

Comment: Thank you. But after adding aaa.conf `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName null
    ServerAlias *
    Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>` it still shows the index.php

Comment: `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` should match the base (non virtual host) config.  I'll update the answer.